# Consulta de sql mostrando un registro repetido

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente consulta que hago en SQL server

```
select celular, razon_social FROM clientes where 
celular <> '' AND LEN(celular) = '10' 
AND ind_estado = '1' AND ISNUMERIC(celular) > 0 
ORDER BY celular
```

me trae registros normalmente, lo que sucede es que hay algunos registros que se repiten en el campo `celular` pero no en el campo `razon_social`

por ejemplo estos registros

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ve en la imagen hay 5 registros: el registro `13` y `14` tienen el mismo número `celular` pero diferente `razon_social`, los registros `15`, `16` y `17` tienen el mismo número `celular` pero diferente `razon_social`.

¿Que es lo que quiero?

que en lugar de traerme esos 5 registros me traiga 2, osea que de los repetidos me traiga solo 1 no importa cual de los repetidos coja, lo que me interesa es que me traiga todos registros excepto si es repetido en el celular, si se repite en el celular solo me trae 1 de los repetidos, pero no quiero que lo excluya.

intente modificando la consulta así

```
select celular, razon_social FROM clientes where 
celular <> '' AND LEN(celular) = '10' 
AND ind_estado = '1' AND ISNUMERIC(celular) > 0 
AND celular in (SELECT celular from clientes GROUP 
BY celular HAVING count(*)=1) 
ORDER BY celular
```

pero me excluye los repetidos

Cabe decir que hay muchos otros registros que se repiten 2, 3 o hasta mas veces en el celular, los que puse son solo algunos ejemplos.

Comment: Si solo quieres que te muestre 2 como dice en tu ejemplo, que pasará con el campo razon_social ya que esos campos no estan repetidos, o solo quieres que te muestre solo el campo celular?

Comment: Lo que sucede es que para mi los registros con el mismo celular son repetidos, así tengan diferente razón social son iguales,  y no puedo borrar duplicados así que tengo que consultar uno por cada 2 o 3 repetidos que haya, así como en el ejemplo

Comment: Ojalá esos datos que muestras no sean números celulares reales. En caso contrario, te invito a editar la pregunta reemplazándolos por datos de prueba falsos

Answer (score 1):

Has probado el group_by sería algo así  básicamente lo que haces es agrupar los elementos de una consulta a través de campo que indicas por lo que si si se repite el campo solo te muestra 1

```
SELECT CLI.celular, (SELECT TOP 1 SUBCL.razon_social FROM 
clientes AS SUBCL WHERE SUBCL.IdCliente = CLI.IdCliente)
FROM clientes AS CLI
WHERE CLI.celular <> '' AND LEN(CLI.celular) = '10' 
AND CLI.ind_estado = '1' AND ISNUMERIC(CLI.celular) > 0 
GROUP BY CLI.celular
ORDER BY CLI.celular
```

Answer (score 0):

Si realmente no le importa la "razón social", considere usar una sub-consulta.

En este caso, asumo que su tabla "clientes" tiene una columna llamada "IdCliente".

Ejemplo:

```
SELECT CLI.celular, (SELECT TOP 1 SUBCL.razon_social FROM clientes AS SUBCL WHERE SUBCL.IdCliente = CLI.IdCliente)
FROM clientes AS CLI
WHERE CLI.celular <> '' AND LEN(CLI.celular) = '10' 
AND CLI.ind_estado = '1' AND ISNUMERIC(CLI.celular) > 0 
ORDER BY CLI.celular
```

Comment: Me sigue mostrando lo mismo.

Comment: @The_pacha ¿puedes crear un script de ejemplo con información de prueba? - así como se hizo en esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/207310/78) - nótese donde dice: `Una base ejemplo sería`.