# Como filtrar por criterio de variación entre fechas en SQL Server

Tags: sql, tsql

Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar con el siguiente problema de la vida real =)

Tengo una BBDD "BD_EJEMPLO" y tabla "Ejemplo_Encuestas" en SQL Server que corresponden a encuestas a clientes y tiene los campos:

- Id_Encuesta
- Id_Cliente
- Fecha_Encuesta
- Calificacion
- Calificacion_Agrupada

Donde:

- Id_Encuesta: Corresponde a un ID único de cada fila.
- Id_Cliente: Es el identificador de cada cliente encuestado y puede
  repetirse. Fecha_Encuesta: Fecha en que se efectuó la encuesta.
- Calificacion: Puntaje relacionado a la encuesta que varía de 0 a 10
  donde 0 es malo y 10 es bueno.
- Calificacion_Agrupada: Agrupamiento del campo anterior "Calificacion"
  para tener solo 3 criterios donde "A" es bueno y corresponde a los
  puntajes 9 y 10, "B" es regular y corresponde a los puntajes 7 y 8 y
  "C" malo y corresponde a los puntajes desde el 0 hasta el 6.

Lo que se quiere marcar "SI"/"NO" en un campo adicional "Variacion_Negativa" aquellos "Id_Cliente" que en el tiempo disminuyeron en su Calificación"/"Calificacion_Agrupada". 
Por decir algunos ejemplos:

- Si un cliente tiene tiene 02 encuestas con calificaciones de mas reciente a mas antiguo {"C";"A"} entonces en la nueva columna debería marcarse como un "SI" ya que disminuyó de "A" a "C".
- Otro cliente {"B";"B";"B";"A"} tiene 04 encuestas, tiene calificación "B" desde hace un tiempo, pero en algún momento fué "A", entonces también debe marcarse como "SI".
- Otro cliente {"A";"A";"A"} siempre tuvo la misma calificación entonces debe marcarse como un "NO".
- Otro cliente {"A";"B";"C"} Actualmente es "A" y antes era "B" varió hacia mejor, debe marcarse como un "NO" ya que solo buscamos aquellos que varían hacia menos.
- Otro {"C"} tiene una sola encuesta, entonces es "NO" ya que no hay variación.

En resumen:
Lo que se busca es marcar en la nueva columna con "SI", SOLO aquellas variaciones a menos comparando la encuesta mas reciente contra la anterior o si la anterior es igual con la variación mas reciente, teniendo en cuenta que el cliente ha tenido mas de una encuesta.

O de lo contrario obtener una nueva tabla con solo aquellos clientes "Id_Cliente" que cumplan con el criterio requerido.

Gracias de antemano a quien pueda ayudarme :)

---

### Una base ejemplo sería:

```
USE [master]
GO /****** Object: Database [BD_EJEMPLO] Script Date: 10/23/2018 17:09:22 ******/
CREATE DATABASE [BD_EJEMPLO] ON PRIMARY (NAME = N'BD_EJEMPLO', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\BD_EJEMPLO.mdf', SIZE = 3072 KB, MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024 KB) LOG ON (NAME = N'BD_EJEMPLO_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\BD_EJEMPLO_log.ldf', SIZE = 1024 KB, MAXSIZE = 2048 GB, FILEGROWTH = 10 %)
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BD_EJEMPLO] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100
GO
IF (1 = FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled'))
BEGIN
  EXEC [BD_EJEMPLO].[dbo].[sp_fulltext_database] @action = 'enable'
END
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BD_EJEMPLO] SET ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BD_EJEMPLO] SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BD_EJEMPLO] SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BD_EJEMPLO] SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BD_EJEMPLO] SET ARITHABORT OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BD_EJEMPLO] SET AUTO_CLOSE OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BD_EJEMPLO] SET AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS ON
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BD_EJEMPLO] SET AUTO_SHRINK OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BD_EJEMPLO] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS ON
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BD_EJEMPLO] SET CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BD_EJEMPLO] SET CURSOR_DEFAULT GLOBAL
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BD_EJEMPLO] SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BD_EJEMPLO] SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BD_EJEMPLO] SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BD_EJEMPLO] SET RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BD_EJEMPLO] SET DISABLE_BROKER
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BD_EJEMPLO] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BD_EJEMPLO] SET DATE_CORRELATION_OPTIMIZATION OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BD_EJEMPLO] SET TRUSTWORTHY OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BD_EJEMPLO] SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BD_EJEMPLO] SET PARAMETERIZATION SIMPLE
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BD_EJEMPLO] SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BD_EJEMPLO] SET HONOR_BROKER_PRIORITY OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BD_EJEMPLO] SET READ_WRITE
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BD_EJEMPLO] SET RECOVERY FULL
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BD_EJEMPLO] SET MULTI_USER
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BD_EJEMPLO] SET PAGE_VERIFY CHECKSUM
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BD_EJEMPLO] SET DB_CHAINING OFF
GO
USE [BD_EJEMPLO]
GO /****** Object: Table [dbo].[Ejemplo_Encuestas] Script Date: 10/23/2018 17:09:22 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Ejemplo_Encuestas] (
  [Id_Encuesta] nvarchar NULL,
  [Id_Cliente] nvarchar NULL,
  [Fecha_Encuesta] [datetime] NULL,
  [Calificacion] [float] NULL,
  [Calificacion_Agrupada] nchar NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Ejemplo_Encuestas] ([Id_Encuesta], [Id_Cliente], [Fecha_Encuesta], [Calificacion], [Calificacion_Agrupada])
  VALUES (N'E1183422', N'15152222', CAST(0x0000A72401166F4C AS datetime), 10, N'A ')
INSERT [dbo].[Ejemplo_Encuestas] ([Id_Encuesta], [Id_Cliente], [Fecha_Encuesta], [Calificacion], [Calificacion_Agrupada])
  VALUES (N'E2761000', N'15887888', CAST(0x0000A85800BD68AC AS datetime), 4, N'C ')
INSERT [dbo].[Ejemplo_Encuestas] ([Id_Encuesta], [Id_Cliente], [Fecha_Encuesta], [Calificacion], [Calificacion_Agrupada])
  VALUES (N'E6111502', N'10005922', CAST(0x0000A8A800153EAC AS datetime), 0, N'C ')
INSERT [dbo].[Ejemplo_Encuestas] ([Id_Encuesta], [Id_Cliente], [Fecha_Encuesta], [Calificacion], [Calificacion_Agrupada])
  VALUES (N'E4370063', N'10005922', CAST(0x0000A82000551DD8 AS datetime), 10, N'A ')
INSERT [dbo].[Ejemplo_Encuestas] ([Id_Encuesta], [Id_Cliente], [Fecha_Encuesta], [Calificacion], [Calificacion_Agrupada])
  VALUES (N'E9213303', N'10014760', CAST(0x0000A97600984B1C AS datetime), 7, N'B ')
INSERT [dbo].[Ejemplo_Encuestas] ([Id_Encuesta], [Id_Cliente], [Fecha_Encuesta], [Calificacion], [Calificacion_Agrupada])
  VALUES (N'E4968314', N'10014760', CAST(0x0000A851003F5F70 AS datetime), 8, N'B ')
INSERT [dbo].[Ejemplo_Encuestas] ([Id_Encuesta], [Id_Cliente], [Fecha_Encuesta], [Calificacion], [Calificacion_Agrupada])
  VALUES (N'E3809315', N'10014760', CAST(0x0000A7F001316220 AS datetime), 9, N'A ')
INSERT [dbo].[Ejemplo_Encuestas] ([Id_Encuesta], [Id_Cliente], [Fecha_Encuesta], [Calificacion], [Calificacion_Agrupada])
  VALUES (N'E2585759', N'10014760', CAST(0x0000A78D00D082E8 AS datetime), 10, N'A ')
INSERT [dbo].[Ejemplo_Encuestas] ([Id_Encuesta], [Id_Cliente], [Fecha_Encuesta], [Calificacion], [Calificacion_Agrupada])
  VALUES (N'E5003484', N'10036018', CAST(0x0000A856005B00E0 AS datetime), 10, N'A ')
INSERT [dbo].[Ejemplo_Encuestas] ([Id_Encuesta], [Id_Cliente], [Fecha_Encuesta], [Calificacion], [Calificacion_Agrupada])
  VALUES (N'E3310246', N'10036018', CAST(0x0000A7C800DB2784 AS datetime), 9, N'A ')
INSERT [dbo].[Ejemplo_Encuestas] ([Id_Encuesta], [Id_Cliente], [Fecha_Encuesta], [Calificacion], [Calificacion_Agrupada])
  VALUES (N'E5160256', N'10050175', CAST(0x0000A863005BE7BC AS datetime), 10, N'A ')
INSERT [dbo].[Ejemplo_Encuestas] ([Id_Encuesta], [Id_Cliente], [Fecha_Encuesta], [Calificacion], [Calificacion_Agrupada])
  VALUES (N'E970395', N'10050175', CAST(0x0000A714010E4A88 AS datetime), 1, N'C ')
INSERT [dbo].[Ejemplo_Encuestas] ([Id_Encuesta], [Id_Cliente], [Fecha_Encuesta], [Calificacion], [Calificacion_Agrupada])
  VALUES (N'E8777911', N'10096264', CAST(0x0000A95900AB2994 AS datetime), 9, N'A ')
INSERT [dbo].[Ejemplo_Encuestas] ([Id_Encuesta], [Id_Cliente], [Fecha_Encuesta], [Calificacion], [Calificacion_Agrupada])
  VALUES (N'E4271133', N'10096264', CAST(0x0000A81800A64BE0 AS datetime), 5, N'C ')
INSERT [dbo].[Ejemplo_Encuestas] ([Id_Encuesta], [Id_Cliente], [Fecha_Encuesta], [Calificacion], [Calificacion_Agrupada])
  VALUES (N'E3149569', N'10096264', CAST(0x0000A7BA00F92F04 AS datetime), 6, N'C ')
INSERT [dbo].[Ejemplo_Encuestas] ([Id_Encuesta], [Id_Cliente], [Fecha_Encuesta], [Calificacion], [Calificacion_Agrupada])
  VALUES (N'E4287335', N'10148833', CAST(0x0000A8190034D244 AS datetime), 8, N'B ')
INSERT [dbo].[Ejemplo_Encuestas] ([Id_Encuesta], [Id_Cliente], [Fecha_Encuesta], [Calificacion], [Calificacion_Agrupada])
  VALUES (N'E2761406', N'10148833', CAST(0x0000A79A00909A5C AS datetime), 9, N'A ')
INSERT [dbo].[Ejemplo_Encuestas] ([Id_Encuesta], [Id_Cliente], [Fecha_Encuesta], [Calificacion], [Calificacion_Agrupada])
  VALUES (N'E6504352', N'32676535', CAST(0x0000A8C500B623BC AS datetime), 8, N'B ')
INSERT [dbo].[Ejemplo_Encuestas] ([Id_Encuesta], [Id_Cliente], [Fecha_Encuesta], [Calificacion], [Calificacion_Agrupada])
  VALUES (N'E5028381', N'32676535', CAST(0x0000A85800BD68AC AS datetime), 9, N'A ')
INSERT [dbo].[Ejemplo_Encuestas] ([Id_Encuesta], [Id_Cliente], [Fecha_Encuesta], [Calificacion], [Calificacion_Agrupada])
  VALUES (N'E3912375', N'32676535', CAST(0x0000A7FA00999A44 AS datetime), 10, N'A ')
INSERT [dbo].[Ejemplo_Encuestas] ([Id_Encuesta], [Id_Cliente], [Fecha_Encuesta], [Calificacion], [Calificacion_Agrupada])
  VALUES (N'E2398215', N'32676535', CAST(0x0000A78000C927B4 AS datetime), 7, N'B ')
INSERT [dbo].[Ejemplo_Encuestas] ([Id_Encuesta], [Id_Cliente], [Fecha_Encuesta], [Calificacion], [Calificacion_Agrupada])
  VALUES (N'E1183763', N'32676535', CAST(0x0000A72401166F4C AS datetime), 8, N'B ')
```

Comment: 1) Para evitar el error: `string or binary data would be truncated` - que es el que yo obtuve al usar su script de prueba, debe colocar la longitud a los campos `Id_Encuesta` y `Id_Cliente`; así: `[Id_Encuesta] nvarchar(50) NULL,
  [Id_Cliente] nvarchar(50) NULL,`.

Comment: El campo Variacion_Negativa es al momento de esa fila, o a ahora??? porque si es a ahora, es bastante mas simple. Si no se necesita un SP complejo...

Comment: Es ahora, con los datos ya registrados anteriormente.

Answer (score 1):

Entonces lo que buscas es la variación de la calificación de cada encuesta con relación a la encuesta anterior por cliente.

Algo como esto:

```
;
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT  E1.*, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id_Cliente ORDER BY Fecha_Encuesta DESC) AS RN
        FROM Ejemplo_Encuestas E1
)
SELECT  T1.Id_Encuesta,
    T1.Id_Cliente,
    T1.Fecha_Encuesta,
    T1.Calificacion_Agrupada,
    CASE WHEN ISNULL(T2.Calificacion_Agrupada, T1.Calificacion_Agrupada) < T1.Calificacion_Agrupada 
        THEN 'SI' 
        ELSE 'NO' 
    END AS 'Variacion'
    FROM CTE T1
    LEFT JOIN CTE T2
        ON T1.Id_Cliente = T2.Id_Cliente 
        AND T1.RN = T2.RN - 1
    ORDER BY T1.Id_Cliente, T1.Fecha_Encuesta DESC
```

Comentarios:

- Usamos una "common table expression" válido a partir de SQL2008
- Básicamente generamos un número de orden para cada cliente y con ese dato, por cada fila buscamos la calificación inmediatamente anterior y hacemos la comparación
- Si solo tiene una calificación comparamos con la misma

Salida:

```
╔═════════════╦════════════╦══════════════════════════╦═══════════════════════╦═══════════╗
║ Id_Encuesta ║ Id_Cliente ║ Fecha_Encuesta           ║ Calificacion_Agrupada ║ Variacion ║
╠═════════════╬════════════╬══════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╬═══════════╣
║ E6111502    ║ 10005922   ║ 19/03/2018 01:17:21 a.m. ║ C                     ║ SI        ║
╠═════════════╬════════════╬══════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╬═══════════╣
║ E4370063    ║ 10005922   ║ 03/11/2017 05:09:54 a.m. ║ A                     ║ NO        ║
╠═════════════╬════════════╬══════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╬═══════════╣
║ E9213303    ║ 10014760   ║ 11/10/2018 09:14:29 a.m. ║ B                     ║ NO        ║
╠═════════════╬════════════╬══════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╬═══════════╣
║ E4968314    ║ 10014760   ║ 22/12/2017 03:50:44 a.m. ║ B                     ║ SI        ║
╠═════════════╬════════════╬══════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╬═══════════╣
║ E3809315    ║ 10014760   ║ 16/09/2017 06:31:52 p.m. ║ A                     ║ NO        ║
╠═════════════╬════════════╬══════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╬═══════════╣
║ E2585759    ║ 10014760   ║ 09/06/2017 12:39:10 p.m. ║ A                     ║ NO        ║
╠═════════════╬════════════╬══════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╬═══════════╣
║ E5003484    ║ 10036018   ║ 27/12/2017 05:31:20 a.m. ║ A                     ║ NO        ║
╠═════════════╬════════════╬══════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╬═══════════╣
║ E3310246    ║ 10036018   ║ 07/08/2017 01:17:55 p.m. ║ A                     ║ NO        ║
╠═════════════╬════════════╬══════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╬═══════════╣
║ E5160256    ║ 10050175   ║ 09/01/2018 05:34:37 a.m. ║ A                     ║ NO        ║
╠═════════════╬════════════╬══════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╬═══════════╣
║ E970395     ║ 10050175   ║ 08/02/2017 04:24:06 p.m. ║ C                     ║ NO        ║
╠═════════════╬════════════╬══════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╬═══════════╣
║ E8777911    ║ 10096264   ║ 12/09/2018 10:23:11 a.m. ║ A                     ║ NO        ║
╠═════════════╬════════════╬══════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╬═══════════╣
║ E4271133    ║ 10096264   ║ 26/10/2017 10:05:28 a.m. ║ C                     ║ NO        ║
╠═════════════╬════════════╬══════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╬═══════════╣
║ E3149569    ║ 10096264   ║ 24/07/2017 03:07:15 p.m. ║ C                     ║ NO        ║
╠═════════════╬════════════╬══════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╬═══════════╣
║ E4287335    ║ 10148833   ║ 27/10/2017 03:12:19 a.m. ║ B                     ║ SI        ║
╠═════════════╬════════════╬══════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╬═══════════╣
║ E2761406    ║ 10148833   ║ 22/06/2017 08:46:29 a.m. ║ A                     ║ NO        ║
╠═════════════╬════════════╬══════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╬═══════════╣
║ E1183422    ║ 15152222   ║ 24/02/2017 04:53:45 p.m. ║ A                     ║ NO        ║
╠═════════════╬════════════╬══════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╬═══════════╣
║ E2761000    ║ 15887888   ║ 29/12/2017 11:29:37 a.m. ║ C                     ║ NO        ║
╠═════════════╬════════════╬══════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╬═══════════╣
║ E6504352    ║ 32676535   ║ 17/04/2018 11:03:09 a.m. ║ B                     ║ SI        ║
╠═════════════╬════════════╬══════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╬═══════════╣
║ E5028381    ║ 32676535   ║ 29/12/2017 11:29:37 a.m. ║ A                     ║ NO        ║
╠═════════════╬════════════╬══════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╬═══════════╣
║ E3912375    ║ 32676535   ║ 26/09/2017 09:19:15 a.m. ║ A                     ║ NO        ║
╠═════════════╬════════════╬══════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╬═══════════╣
║ E2398215    ║ 32676535   ║ 27/05/2017 12:12:23 p.m. ║ B                     ║ NO        ║
╠═════════════╬════════════╬══════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╬═══════════╣
║ E1183763    ║ 32676535   ║ 24/02/2017 04:53:45 p.m. ║ B                     ║ NO        ║
╚═════════════╩════════════╩══════════════════════════╩═══════════════════════╩═══════════╝
```

Por último, si solo quieres comparar la última encuesta con la anterior inmediata, puedes hacer:

```
;
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT  E1.*, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id_Cliente ORDER BY Fecha_Encuesta DESC) AS RN
        FROM Ejemplo_Encuestas E1
)
SELECT  T1.Id_Encuesta,
    T1.Id_Cliente,
    T1.Fecha_Encuesta,
    T1.Calificacion_Agrupada,
    CASE WHEN ISNULL(T2.Calificacion_Agrupada, T1.Calificacion_Agrupada) < T1.Calificacion_Agrupada 
        THEN 'SI' 
        ELSE 'NO' 
    END AS 'Variacion'
    FROM CTE T1
    LEFT JOIN CTE T2
        ON T1.Id_Cliente = T2.Id_Cliente 
        -- Solo comparamos la última
        AND T1.RN = T2.RN - 1
    WHERE T1.RN = 1
    ORDER BY T1.Id_Cliente, T1.Fecha_Encuesta DESC
```

Comment: Exacto amigo, solo habría un paso adicional y uno mas si no fuera mucha molestia.

Comment: @Carlos_JPQ, revisa mi última edición. Saludos.

Comment: De la tabla que has obtenido, faltaría sacar un resumen de la ultima iteracción s/fecha por que eso determina si es un SI/NO para cada cliente, es decir un resumen donde no se repita cada Id_Cliente que corresponda a la fecha mas reciente con su respectivo SI/NO.

Comment: -(*opcional) Ese campo "Calificación_Agrupada" no es propia de la fuente donde extraigo la información, yo la he agregado con un left Join ¿como podía incrustrarla directamente en la consulta que has hecho? para no generar una tabla adicional, ya que las fuentes son medianamente grandes alrededor de unos 900000 registros con 100 campos y tienen mucho texto, osea para que no se haga muy pesado. (disculpa el abuso, pero es por que no me sale esto desde ya hace buen tiempo).

Comment: Lo que dices es que `Calificación_Agrupada` no forma parte de `Ejemplo_Encuestas`?, si es así debes agregar la tabla mediante el `JOIN` pertinente en la definición de la CTE (la consulta que está dentro del `WITH CTE AS (...)`)

Comment: Me salió como indicaste, muchas gracias !!!!!!!