# ¿Cómo detectar si los valores dentro de un resultado son iguales?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy intentando responder esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/207310/78) en donde básicamente estoy usando este acercamiento.

Tengo una variable llamada `@variacion` y su valor será determinado así:

- Si los resultados de la columna `Calificacion_Agrupada` son diferentes, coloco el valor `@variacion` a "SI".
- Si solo hay 1 resultado ó los resultados de la columna `Calificacion_Agrupada` son iguales, establezco el valor de la variable `@variacion` a "NO".

Este es un ejemplo de los resultados de la encuesta del cliente "10096264":

```
----------  ----------  -----------------------     -------------   ---------------------
Id_Encuesta Id_Cliente  Fecha_Encuesta              Calificacion    Calificacion_Agrupada
----------  ----------  -----------------------     -------------   ---------------------
E8777911    10096264    2018-09-12 10:23:11.000     9               A
E4271133    10096264    2017-10-26 10:05:28.000     5               C
E3149569    10096264    2017-07-24 15:07:15.000     6               C
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Aquí se puede ver que los resultados de la columna `Calificacion_Agrupada` NO son iguales *(por lo tanto, el valor de `@variacion` sería "NO")*.

Estoy intentando definir el valor de la variable `@variacion` sin usar `WHILE`<sup>1</sup>.

¿Cómo detectar si los valores dentro de un resultado son iguales?

---

<sup>1</sup> Mi idea era inicialmente usar un `WHILE` para recorrer estos resultados del cliente "10096264" mirar si el siguiente registro es diferente al anterior; pero no me parece la mejor manera de hacer esta verificación.

Comment: Ojo, porque la respuesta a esta, no responde la otra... y while porque pensabas hacer un SP?

Comment: comparte tu codigo para poder ayudarte

Comment: @gbianchi solo estoy intentando responder a la pregunta. Todavía no tengo una respuesta completa.

Comment: Es que esto se resuelve con un min y un simple group by.. porque en realidad no necesitas todos los registros, si no el ultimo y el anterior y copiar el resultado que venias trayendo.. Igual fijate que OP no dio señales de vida.

Comment: @gbianchi tienes razón. Me gustaría saber cómo resolverías este caso "mi pregunta" en específico. *La verdad no soy mu bueno en SQL y creo que me podría ayudar en futuras actividades*.

Comment: Fijate el comentario que deje en la otra pregunta. Es muy distinto si lo queres por filas, a si lo queres a este momento. Si el campo variacion esta en otra tabla (lo que parece logico), entonces solo tenes que tomar el nuevo, verificar si es mejor que el anterior y termina ahi.. si es por cada "fila", ahi si es un proceso mas complejo..

Answer (score 1):

No entendí si quieres que esto ocurra en 1 sola sentencia, pero una forma fácil de hacerlo, y quizás sin la mejor optimización de código, sin while, sería:

```
DECLARE @variacion CHAR(2)

SET @variacion = 'SI'

SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT CALIFICACION_AGRUPADA)
FROM
    TABLA_A
GROUP BY CALIFICACION_AGRUPADA

IF @@ROWCOUNT > 1 BEGIN
    SET @variacion = 'NO'
END

SELECT @variacion
```

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte y bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). Saludos.